# got the Excel file from Pandas If you save it again, the date will not be saved

Tags: python, pandas, date

Creation code:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import openpyxl

excel_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
file_path = r'c:/p_py/totodate.xlsx'
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
sheet = workbook.Sheets(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(sheet.UsedRange())
df1 = df.copy()

new_header = df1.iloc[0]
df = df1[1:]
df1.columns = new_header
print(df1['today'].dtype)

df1.to_excel('c:/p_py/totodate1.xlsx')
```

Excel original file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzyZ1.png)

File after saving Excel :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozws4.png)

The Excel file with the date on Pandas
After blowing it
How can the date be saved when saving
Want.